# Creating flv from image in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, flv

I'm trying to make flv file from images via the following Matlab code.The problem is converting bmp images fo flv.
I'm almost new in this section of Matlab. do you have any Idea?

```
clear 
clc
vidobj = videoinput('winvideo',2);
preview(vidobj);
No_snapshot = 5; 
interval    = 1; 
Format = 'bmp';
PathName = uigetdir;
    tic;
    count = 0;
    date_temp = datevec(now);
    date_string_vid = [num2str(date_temp(1)),'-',num2str(date_temp(2)),'-',num2str(date_temp(3)),'-',...
    num2str(date_temp(4)),'-',num2str(date_temp(5)),'-',num2str(date_temp(6))];

    while 1
        if fix(toc/interval) > count
            count = fix(toc/interval);
            date_string = num2str(count);
            imwrite(getsnapshot(vidobj),[PathName,'\',date_string,'.' Format], Format);
        end

        if count >= No_snapshot 
            break;
        end
    end
closepreview;
delete(vidobj);
% =========================================================================
PathName = 'G:\capture_video\movie1\';
obj=VideoWriter(date_string_vid,'Grayscale AVI');
open(obj)
for m=1:No_snapshot

m1=imread([PathName,num2str(m),'.bmp']);
% m1=double(m1(:,:,1));
F = im2frame(m1);
aviObject = addframe(obj,F);  % Add the frame to the AVI file
end
close(obj)
```

Comment: I also read this post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637589/how-do-i-record-video-from-a-webcam-in-matlab).

Comment: You're writing to an AVI container, yet you want to create a FLV video.  You do realize that they are different video standards, right?  http://www.video-to-flash.com/avi_vs_flv/ .  I also don't understand why you need to write images to disk, then read those images from disk to write to the file.  Can't you just use the images stored in memory in your first loop and directly write these to your video?