# Change input video from saved video to streaming video for manipulation

Tags: matlab, video

I downloaded this code from MIT's video magnification lab: http://people.csail.mit.edu/mrub/evm/#code

Except it currently only runs on saved videos. We wanted to change it so that we can have a live video set up.

The matlab code is as follows:

dataDir = './data';
resultsDir = 'ResultsSIGGRAPH2012';

```
mkdir(resultsDir);

inFile = fullfile(dataDir,'face2.mp4');
fprintf('Processing %s\n', inFile);

% Motion
amplify_spatial_lpyr_temporal_butter(inFile,resultsDir,20,80, ...
                                     0.5,10,30, 0);
```

The amplify_spatial_lpyr_temporal_butter matlab code is:

```
function amplify_spatial_lpyr_temporal_butter(vidFile, outDir ...
    ,alpha, lambda_c, fl, fh ...
    ,samplingRate, chromAttenuation)

    [low_a, low_b] = butter(1, fl/samplingRate, 'low');
    [high_a, high_b] = butter(1, fh/samplingRate, 'low');

    [~,vidName] = fileparts(vidFile);

    outName = fullfile(outDir,[vidName '-butter-from-' num2str(fl) '-to-' ...
        num2str(fh) '-alpha-' num2str(alpha) '-lambda_c-' num2str(lambda_c) ...
        '-chromAtn-' num2str(chromAttenuation) '.avi']);

    % Read video
    vid = VideoReader(vidFile);
    % Extract video info
    vidHeight = vid.Height;
    vidWidth = vid.Width;
    nChannels = 3;
    fr = vid.FrameRate;
    len = vid.NumberOfFrames;
    temp = struct('cdata', ...
          zeros(vidHeight, vidWidth, nChannels, 'uint8'), ...
          'colormap', []);

    startIndex = 1;
    endIndex = len-10;

    vidOut = VideoWriter(outName);
    vidOut.FrameRate = fr;

    open(vidOut)

    % firstFrame
    temp.cdata = read(vid, startIndex);
    [rgbframe,~] = frame2im(temp);
    rgbframe = im2double(rgbframe);
    frame = rgb2ntsc(rgbframe);

    [pyr,pind] = buildLpyr(frame(:,:,1),'auto');
    pyr = repmat(pyr,[1 3]);
    [pyr(:,2),~] = buildLpyr(frame(:,:,2),'auto');
    [pyr(:,3),~] = buildLpyr(frame(:,:,3),'auto');
    lowpass1 = pyr;
    lowpass2 = pyr;
    pyr_prev = pyr;

    output = rgbframe;
    writeVideo(vidOut,im2uint8(output));

    nLevels = size(pind,1);

    for i=startIndex+1:endIndex

            progmeter(i-startIndex,endIndex - startIndex + 1);

            temp.cdata = read(vid, i);
            [rgbframe,~] = frame2im(temp);

            rgbframe = im2double(rgbframe);
            frame = rgb2ntsc(rgbframe);

            [pyr(:,1),~] = buildLpyr(frame(:,:,1),'auto');
            [pyr(:,2),~] = buildLpyr(frame(:,:,2),'auto');
            [pyr(:,3),~] = buildLpyr(frame(:,:,3),'auto');

            %% temporal filtering
            lowpass1 = (-high_b(2) .* lowpass1 + high_a(1).*pyr + ...
            high_a(2).*pyr_prev)./high_b(1);
            lowpass2 = (-low_b(2) .* lowpass2 + low_a(1).*pyr + ...
            low_a(2).*pyr_prev)./low_b(1);

            filtered = (lowpass1 - lowpass2);

            pyr_prev = pyr;     

            %% amplify each spatial frequency bands according to Figure 6 of our paper
            ind = size(pyr,1);

            delta = lambda_c/8/(1+alpha);

            % the factor to boost alpha above the bound we have in the
            % paper. (for better visualization)
            exaggeration_factor = 2;

            % compute the representative wavelength lambda for the lowest spatial 
            % freqency band of Laplacian pyramid

            lambda = (vidHeight^2 + vidWidth^2).^0.5/3; % 3 is experimental constant

            for l = nLevels:-1:1
              indices = ind-prod(pind(l,:))+1:ind;

              % compute modified alpha for this level
              currAlpha = lambda/delta/8 - 1;
              currAlpha = currAlpha*exaggeration_factor;

              if (l == nLevels || l == 1) % ignore the highest and lowest frequency band
                  filtered(indices,:) = 0;
              elseif (currAlpha > alpha)  % representative lambda exceeds lambda_c
                  filtered(indices,:) = alpha*filtered(indices,:);
              else
                  filtered(indices,:) = currAlpha*filtered(indices,:);
              end

              ind = ind - prod(pind(l,:));
              % go one level down on pyramid, 
              % representative lambda will reduce by factor of 2
              lambda = lambda/2; 
            end


            %% Render on the input video
            output = zeros(size(frame));

            output(:,:,1) = reconLpyr(filtered(:,1),pind);
            output(:,:,2) = reconLpyr(filtered(:,2),pind);
            output(:,:,3) = reconLpyr(filtered(:,3),pind);

            output(:,:,2) = output(:,:,2)*chromAttenuation; 
            output(:,:,3) = output(:,:,3)*chromAttenuation;

            output = frame + output;

            output = ntsc2rgb(output); 
%             filtered = rgbframe + filtered.*mask;

            output(output > 1) = 1;
            output(output < 0) = 0;

            writeVideo(vidOut,im2uint8(output));

    end
    close(vidOut);
end
```

We are trying to get it to work with a streaming video input, but don't really know where to start. We are somewhat familiar with programming but not so familiar with Matlab and so don't really know where to look for such answers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at the answer of Richard to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12492238/2732801 It contains everything you need. Don't use the accepted answer, you are planning to do some processing so having a buffered video input is better.

Comment: I managed to get all of that working, except for buffered processing. Is there a way that I can have two preview windows. One of the original and one of the processed video running in real-time (or slightly soon thereafter)?